# TFS 2012 - adding files to solution and dragging files from solution explorer to active doc

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I just added a TFS project to my vs2012 pro trial and I have 2 questions.

**1 -** When I try to add an existing item to my source controlled project I get the following message

"You are attempting to add an item to a source-controlled project, but the item's path has no mapping.  If you continue with the add, this item will not be added to source control.  Do you wish to proceed with the add?"

In my work environment this doesn't seem to be a problem.

**2 -** I can't seem to drag files from the solution explorer to the current document I'm working on.

For example, if I try to drag a JS file and drop it into an HTML doc im working on, nothing happens. This works on normal projects, so I'm guessing it's some settings.

Here are some of the settings I have on for my TFS project.

Team > Team Project Settings > Source Control > Enable multiple check out is unchecked

Team > Team Project Collection Settings > Source Control > Workspace Settings > Server is checked as default.

I used those since I want files to be locked when one person is editing them.

Any tips on how to fix these?

Thanks,

Ankeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map your workspace at the Project level. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx) will guide you through on how to set up the source control folder structure.